# Running a method every 15 minutes, every day, between certain times

Tags: java, timer, calendar, timezone, frequency

I want to run a method every 15 minutes, every day, between 08:01:00 and 16:31:00 London time.

So something like this:

```
foo(); //run every 15 mins, everyday, between 08:01:00 and 16:31:00.

public void foo(){
//do stuff
}
```

I have tried using Calendar and Timer but I cannot get this to work.

Thanks for our help.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you cannot let the OS scheduler (Windows Task Scheduler, cron, etc.) handle this? If you insist putting the scheduler into your code, look into [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) before re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Which OS are you running on? Does your application run as a daemon? You can use OS schedulers to run your application like Cron

Comment: If the above comments do not suit you for whatever reason, try using Scheduled Executors as a last resort.

Comment: I'm on windows. I did not know about OS schedulers actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [quartz-scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/index.html)

I have been using it for a while and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

I hope here we are talking about running any job in JAVA.
So, in java We have `SchedulerFactory` which schedules Job based on the Cron Expression given to it.

```
//Create instance of factory
    SchedulerFactory schedulerFactory=new StdSchedulerFactory();

    //Get schedular
    Scheduler scheduler= schedulerFactory.getScheduler();

    //Create JobDetail object specifying which Job you want to execute
    JobDetail jobDetail=new JobDetail("myJobClass","myJob1",MyJob.class);

    //Associate Trigger to the Job
    CronTrigger trigger=new CronTrigger("cronTrigger","myJob1","0 0/1 * * * ?");

    //Pass JobDetail and trigger dependencies to schedular
    scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail,trigger);

    //Start schedular
    scheduler.start();
```

MyJob.class

```
public class MyJob implements Job{

      @Override
      public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
                 System.out.println("Your Logic");
        }

    }
```

Now for your chron job it will be something like,

```
*/15 7-16 * * *
```

You can check out more about chrome job [Here](https://crontab.guru/#*/15_8-16_*_*_*)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Do I need to extend an abstract class, because it cannot instantiate JobDetail and CronTrigger constructors?

Comment: for more examples you can refer to quartz official site. http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/examples/

Answer (score 0):

Use timertask:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36jbBSQd3eU

For every 1000 milisecond you run your code (each second). You then check LocalTime.now() - with your time.

if time is true call your method (and set a global boolean variable back to false). Else do nothing.

Another preformence point is that a thread (on my own computer) runs 1 235 102 times in 10 seconds. A timertask would run 10 times in 10 seconds.

You will be off within a second doing this.

Comment: That's a terrible way of doing it. Akin to children sitting in the back seat of the car. Are we there yet? No. Are we there yet? No. Are we there yet? No. Are we there yet? No. Are we there yet? Yes

Comment: Thats how a listener work though. However it would be probably be better to use a proper listener - to execute code on time changed

Comment: Huh? That's how a poller works... not a listener!!! And polling is a poor use of resources

Comment: How would a kid know when to ask - if not always. As far as I know listeners  in a thread - running a speed, continiously checking something.

Comment: The kids in the back seat example is an example of polling. The listener example is the parent telling the kids "we're here" and the kid saying "yay"... once

Comment: How can time tell something thing when they should happen? you listen for time not the opposite

Comment: See [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

Comment: You need to schedule it with time though, not just running seprately from it.

Comment: Seriously... if you wrote code that polled every second in my shop... I'd fire you

Comment: my processor speed is 3600000000 cycles per second. You cant to tell my computer when it should know a second has passed. something external is not starting my computer each second - teling it a sceond has passed. The parent cant tell anything to a child if the child is not listenting. It cannot even tell it to listen... point is that you have processor speed. And you have threads in a computer, also running at a speed. In a timertask speed is limited to miliseconds. Which is 1000 checks each second. Thats nothing compared to 3600000000 each second. 1 herts is one cycle per second.

Comment: Honestly... give up!!! There are 900 seconds in 15 minutes. If you are checking every second that's 899 wasted operations. By using ScheduledExecutorService (or Quartz etc) you are using the operating system's scheduler which is far more efficient than your polling idea.

Comment: I was wrong about the listeners, listeners are in fact not listeners but dead pieces of code activated by events. The ScheduledExecutorService does not help you start at the right time - so I don't understand why you criticise "polling". How are you supposed to sync clocks - if not "polling".